# opening up exe with multiple forms without killing the process

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Environment: vb.net, win forms and VS2010

I have two applications A & B. B has two forms F1 and F2 that open from application A. Now the below code successfully opens the Application B forms. I have a very specific requirement...

If application B - F1 is open and the user wants to open F2, the application B comes to the front but F1 still displays as the current form. In below code "IsProcessRunning", i can check and kill application B process if F2 is not open and then re-open application B with F2. But my requirement is to open F2 without killing the application B process. In application B, frmMain (MDI) is the main entry point. How can i achieve this?

If above is not possible, is it possible that when i kill application B, that application B frmMain - form closing event should fire so that i can take care of certain actions which are really important.

Here is current code:

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Click handle to open - all buttons need to call this action 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="titleArg">Title to be passed to the ScaleApps as Argument </param>
    ''' <param name="windowTitle">The part of the name for the form as showing in the process title under ctrl+alt+del</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub HandleClick(ByVal titleArg As String, ByVal windowTitle As String)
        Dim exeLocation As String = curSettings.ExeLocation
        Dim processName As String = "MyApps" 'EXE name. Do not add .EXE
        Dim isRunning As Boolean = IsProcessRunning(processName, windowTitle, True)
        If Not isRunning Then
            isRunning = OpenProcess(exeLocation, processName, titleArg, windowTitle)
        End If
        BringProcessToFront(processName)
    End Sub
 
 
#Region "Helper Functions"
 
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
 
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function ShowWindow(handle As IntPtr, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
 
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function IsIconic(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens the prossess and passes the specified arguments to it
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="exeLocation">EXE full qualified path</param>
    ''' <param name="processName">The process name without .exe</param>
    ''' <param name="titleArg">The title Argumemt getting passed to the EXE</param>
    ''' <param name="windowTitle">The window title showing in processes</param>
    ''' <returns>True/False</returns>
    Private Function OpenProcess(ByVal exeLocation As String, ByVal processName As String, ByVal titleArg As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As Boolean
        Dim isRunning As Boolean = False
        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(processName) Then
                Message("Process name missing!", zMsgTypes.Err)
                Return False
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exeLocation) Then
                Message("Exe location not specified in the cfg file!", zMsgTypes.Err)
                Return False
            ElseIf Not File.Exists(exeLocation) Then
                Message("Exe location doesn't exist. Please open cfg file and update setting" & vbCrLf & exeLocation, zMsgTypes.Err)
                Return False
            End If
 
            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
            psi.FileName = exeLocation
            psi.Arguments = titleArg & " " & curStatus.UserID
            psi.UseShellExecute = True
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(psi)
            'isRunning = IsProcessRunning(processName, windowTitle, False)
            isRunning = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            putHistory("OpenProcess Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return isRunning
    End Function
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Brings the App to the front
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="processName">The process name without .exe</param>
    Private Sub BringProcessToFront(ByVal processName As String)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(processName) Then
            Message("Process name missing!", zMsgTypes.Err)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            'here we're going to get a list of all running processes on the computer and then will check out process
            Dim pf As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
            If pf.Length > 0 Then
                Dim handle As IntPtr
                For Each procP As Process In pf
                    'check and bring to the front
                    handle = procP.MainWindowHandle
                    If handle <> 0 Then 'Do we have a handle; if only want to being minimized window to front then add IsIconic to the if as well
                        ShowWindow(handle, 9)
                        SetForegroundWindow(handle)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            putHistory("BringProcessToFront Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Checks if the process is running
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="processName">The process name without .exe</param>
    ''' <param name="windowTitle">The window title</param>
    ''' <param name="isKillProcess">Kill process if the windowTitle is not found</param>
    ''' <returns>True/False</returns>
    Private Function IsProcessRunning(ByVal processName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String, ByVal isKillProcess As Boolean) As Boolean
        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(processName) Then
                Message("Process name missing!", zMsgTypes.Err)
                Return False
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowTitle) Then
                Message("Window title missing!", zMsgTypes.Err)
                Return False
            End If
 
            Dim myTitle As String = ""
            For Each pf As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
                If pf.ProcessName.ToUpper.StartsWith(processName.ToUpper) Then
                    myTitle = pf.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper
                    If Not myTitle.Contains(windowTitle.ToUpper) Then
                        'Do not kill, find another way to tell the tartget exe to open the new form
                        'If isKillProcess Then
                        '    pf.Kill()
                        'End If
                        'Return False ' do not kill
                        Return True
                    End If
                    If pf.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper.Contains(windowTitle.ToUpper) Then
                        Return True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            putHistory("IsProcessRunning Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
  
#End Region
```

Comment: Why are you not using the [Make Single Instance Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fz4ssw2(v=vs.100).aspx) feature for application "B"?  You can pass it a command line parameter to indicate which form should be displayed.  This will trigger the [StartupNextInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.100).aspx) event where you can take action accordingly.

Comment: I didn't built this app so not sure about the decisions made.I'll look into single instance application. Please put your comment as an answer so that  i accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Make Single Instance Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fz4ssw2(v=vs.100).aspx) feature for application "B".  You can pass it a command line parameter to indicate which form should be displayed. This will trigger the [StartupNextInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.100).aspx) event where you can take action accordingly.